# Using search with property bag only give my one result

Tags: search, property-bag

I'm testing to tag site with a property bag for use with search. My problem is that if I have two sites with the same value in the property bag. Only the first one is shown in the Search Center, or if I try to get the results in CSOM. But if I use a "Content by Search" WebPart i get both/all. If I give the property a different value it works.

What am I missing, why it is just showing the first site that was given the property with a specific value, not all?

Comment: Is the trim duplicates option enabled in your search results? Could be why one is hidden/missing.

Comment: @EricAlexander This worked, thank you. Post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the trim duplicates option is enabled, trimming away similar results. Try unchecking this option.